Documentation around SentTransferredFile and required properties in Info.plist
TL;DR It appears that SentTransferredFile requires Info.plist entries, but am searching for documentation/videos that explains the reason in case there are other considerations here.
==
I have been struggling with an issue that involves a file exported using a FileRepresentation and SentTransferredFile.
extension LoanXLSX: Transferable {
    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        FileRepresentation(exportedContentType: .loan) { document in
            // Generate an XLSX document and retrieve its path...
            let url = URL(filePath: path)
            return SentTransferredFile(url)
        }
    }
}

The app can share through most mechanisms, but when using Save to Files, the system attempts to present the File Browser through the SaveToFiles process, but it opens a blank sheet, then closes it before rendering anything. Inside my app, this message is logged:
cancelled request - error: The operation couldn’t be completed. Invalid argument

Checking the Console, I see this error associated with the SaveToFiles process.
completing requestwith error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=22 "Invalid argument"

Over the past couple days, I finally found someone discussing LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace and UIFileSharingEnabled. Upon enabling these, the problem disappeared. After more experimentation, it seems UISupportsDocumentBrowser also resolves the problem (without the other properties).
My question: does anyone have any experience with this issue, and do you know where I can find any documentation or WWDC videos discussing it? Also, if anyone else encounters this, maybe this post can save you a couple weeks. Thanks in advance.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I'm having the same problems with videos lying in my caches directory... Did you come up with a solution? @lucasgladding

@heyfrank The solution above worked for the documents directory, but I am seeing the same issue using a temp directory, so I am investigating again. I'll update here if I find any more info. This is one lead in case you want to pursue the same:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/735726
